# How do you convert a thrift object to Json in python?

Tags: python, thrift

I've tried to convert a thrift object to json in python.

If I try to use `json.dumps(thriftObj)`, it fails with the following:

`TypeError: MyThriftObj(...) is not JSON serializable`

I tried fixing it with a default function:

`json.dumps(thriftObj, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)`

This worked in some cases but in other cases I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'DictProxy' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

How do I convert a valid thrift object to json?

Answer (score 5):

Thrift comes with a serialization library that you can use. Most of the documentation I found for this is in Java or other languages but the library does exist in python. See below for some code you can use:

```
from thrift.TSerialization import serialize
from thrift.protocol.TJSONProtocol import TSimpleJSONProtocolFactory

def thrift_to_json(thrift_object):
  return serialize(thrift_object, protocol_factory=TSimpleJSONProtocolFactory())
```

Comment: For me, I see a `Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable` error with this code alone. To resolve, you'll need to call `.decode("utf-8")` to the serialized object.

Comment: maybe convert to a string first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use package [`thriftpy2`](https://thriftpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Hope the snippets below could help:

```
import thriftpy2.protocol.json as proto

json_data = proto.struct_to_json(thrift_data)
```

where you can replace `json_data` and `thrift_data` with your own variables.

Comment: Any idea how to convert thrift struct to spark struct as I am unable to access the variables inside the thrift struct