# Deserialize Kafka Thrift message with PySpark Streaming to JSON

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, databricks, json-deserialization, thrift

I am using databricks environment and reading a Kafka input.

The messages consumed from Kafka are in Thrift Binary and am having issues deserialize it to JSON.

I am writing an UDF to do this, but am unable to figure out how to convert thrift -> JSON?

I have tried

```
import thriftpy2.protocol.json as proto
    
def decoder(thrift_data):
  return proto.struct_to_json(thrift_data)

which throws an error PythonException: 'AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute 'thrift_spec''
```

and also tried

```
def decoder(thrift_data):
  return serialize(thrift_data, protocol_factory=TSimpleJSONProtocolFactory())

which throws an error PythonException: 'AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute 'write'',
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016810/how-do-you-convert-a-thrift-object-to-json-in-python ?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes, I tried the methods mentioned there but they throw an error

Comment: Add to your post the code that you tried & error. Right now it's too generic

Comment: Did you try this package?
https://github.com/wayhome/thrift_json
>>> from thrift_json import thrift2json, thrift2dict
>>> json_str = thrfit2json(thrift_obj)

Comment: @BennyElgazar The data is in Thrift Binary